# Trigger button event manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button

I have a `asp:Button` that has an `Onclientclick Event` do some operation.

I want to trigger this `OnclientClick` manually using JavaScript or Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This being webforms, you'll want to do something like this:

```
$("#<%= ASPButtonID.ClientID %>").click();
```

where ASPButtonID is the name of your button.

In response to your comment:
Add a click handler like so:

```
$($("#<%= ASPButtonID.ClientID %>").click(function(){ 
   // call your JS function from here 
}););
```

and then make the call above

Comment: Hi King,
I have tried this one.
But this is triggering the onclick function in Code behind.

I want to trigger the Javascript Function of Onclick Event.

I cant call directly the Javascript Function in my code.

Thats why  i need to trigger this Button Client Click Event>

Comment: Then add this to your javascript: 
$($("#<%= ASPButtonID.ClientID %>").click(function(){
 // call your JS function from here
}););

Leave the other code in as well. It will still trigger code behind event. If you don't want that, maybe this button shouldn't be asp:button and should be a simple html control.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonID").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger the button's click event using this:

```
$("#buttonID").click();
```